# logistic regression using CIFAR-10 dataset

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning

i have appended data from data files in cifar10-dataset into numpy arrays:

```
train_dataset=np.ndarray((50000,3072),dtype=np.float32)
train_labels=np.ndarray(50000,dtype=np.float32)
```

and from training file into:

```
test_data=np.ndarray((10000,3072),dtype=np.float32)
test_labels=np.ndarray(10000,dtype=np.float32

sample_size = 1000
regr = LogisticRegression()
X_train = train_dataset[:sample_size]
y_train = train_labels[:sample_size]
%time regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
regr.score(test_data_final, test_labels_final)
```

I get the following output:

```
CPU times: user 19.8 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 19.8 s
Wall time: 20.2 s
Out[11]:
0.24940000000000001
```

Is this the correct way of running the logistic regression on the data?
Or should i reshape the data because each array  consists of 3072(32*32*3) values of (R-G-B)32* 32*32 image?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can pass an N-dimensional data set (e.g. `[10000, 32, 32, 3]` instead of `[10000, 3072]`) to the logistic regression classifier? Have you tried it?

Comment: Everything is fine in this approach.